# Show Hide Text using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to use  show/hide for text using jQuery but the problem is that it was made with jQuery version 1.7.2 and I am using jQuery version 3.1.1. Now when I change the library to 3.1.1 in JsFiddle this demo doesn't work anymore. I believe that some functions used here got deprecated and hence need an update. Can anybody help me update this bit of code for 3.1.1? Any help would be appreciated.

```js
$(".show-more a").on("click", function() {
    var $this = $(this); 
    var $content = $this.parent().prev("div.content");
    var linkText = $this.text().toUpperCase();    
    
    if(linkText === "SHOW MORE"){
        linkText = "Show less";
        $content.switchClass("hideContent", "showContent", 400);
    } else {
        linkText = "Show more";
        $content.switchClass("showContent", "hideContent", 400);
    };

    $this.text(linkText);
});
```

```css
<div class="text-container">
    <h1>Title goes here</h1>
    <h2>Subtitle</h2>
    <div class="content hideContent">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
        <p>Some more text</p>
        <ul>
            <li>Some more text</li>
            <li>Some more text</li>
            <li>Some more text</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="show-more">
        <a href="#">Show more</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text-container">
    <h1>Title goes here</h1>
    <h2>Subtitle</h2>
    <div class="content hideContent">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
        <p>Some more text</p>
        <ul>
            <li>Some more text</li>
            <li>Some more text</li>
            <li>Some more text</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="show-more">
        <a href="#">Show more</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You'll notice in the fiddle's JavaScript options under _"Frameworks & Extensions"_ section you have enabled _jQuery UI 1.8.18_

Comment: @Phil so if I can't use `switchClass` now what should I use instead?

Comment: @AurazoScript, You could swap `$content.switchClass("hideContent", "showContent", 400);` for `$content.toggleClass('hideContent showContent');`. You will lose the animation though.

Comment: @ItsPete thanks, it worked. That's what I was looking for. And yes, the animation is lost but I found its better without it :D You could have posted it as an answer. Would have accepted it.

Answer (score 1):

the method you are using, `switchClass`, is a part of jQuery UI. jQuery UI is a library built on top of the core jQuery library. That's why when you switch to jQuery 3.1.1 it isn't working.

> jQuery UI provides abstractions for low-level interaction and animation, advanced effects and high-level, themeable widgets, built on top of the jQuery JavaScript Library, that you can use to build highly interactive web applications.

Comment: Thanks for the information. But what is the appropriate solution to this now?

Answer (score 0):

A workaround for `switchClass` will be `addClass` with `removeClass`

```js
 $(".show-more a").on("click", function() {
        var $this = $(this); 
        var $content = $this.parent().prev("div.content");
        var linkText = $this.text().toUpperCase();    
        
        if(linkText === "SHOW MORE"){
            linkText = "Show less";
            $content.addClass('showContent').removeClass('hideContent');
        } else {
            linkText = "Show more";
            $content.addClass("hideContent").removeClass("showContent");
        };
    
        $this.text(linkText);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <div class="text-container">
        <h1>Title goes here</h1>
        <h2>Subtitle</h2>
        <div class="content hideContent">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
            <p>Some more text</p>
            <ul>
                <li>Some more text</li>
                <li>Some more text</li>
                <li>Some more text</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="show-more">
            <a href="#">Show more</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```